# split dataframe by factor and name new df by the factor and addidtional description like "new_dataframe(factor)"

Tags: r, dataframe, split, lapply, names

I need to `split` my df into several new df by a factor via loop. Problem, the factor consist of numbers, and the new df are called `"1"` `"2"` and so on, this makes it hard to call them for the next pice of code,... Any help how I can rename/name the new df´s. like `new_df_1`, `new_df_2`?

what I have so far:

```
new_df<- split(df, df$cluster)
new_names <- as.character(unique(df$cluster))
for (i in 1:length(new_df))
{assign(new_names[i],new_df[[i]])}
```

I also tried `lapply`but was only able to save, not to make a df in the Global Environment, as I actually don´t need it saved for later.

```
new_df<- split(df, df$cluster)
lapply(names(new_df),function(nm)
write.csv(new_df[[nm]],paste("new_df",nm,".csv")))
```

It works, but makes a file: `new_df 1.csv`

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: It is better not to make global variables.  Iinstead have it as a `list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cluster_list <- split(df, f = df$clust)`

builds the cluster list, to manipulate the list use:  `lapply`.

Answer (score 1):

If we need objects in the global environment, use `list2env`

```
names(new_df) <- paste(new_df, seq_along(new_df), sep="_")
list2env(new_df, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

NOTE: Not recommended to create multiple global objects.  Instead, it can be all processed as a `list` ('new_df')

---

Or using `assign`

```
nm1 <- names(new_df) # after creating the names with `paste`
for (nm in nm1) {
      assign(nm,new_df[[i]])
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick suggestions! I used the `list2env` approach, but R calculates for ever and finally crash (my `df` is big, `1135 obs. of 22384 variables`). Before I used the loop, `subset` was quite fast `new_df_1<-subset(df,cluster==1,select= -cluster)`

Comment: @KonradWeber  I would not recommend creating these many variables in your global space.  It should be kept in  a `list` and use `lapply/sapply` etc to process/manipulate the contents

Comment: sounds the way to go, but the `list`help doesn't help me a lot,  any suggestions for any related examples, thx!

Comment: @KonradWeber  Can you describe why a list doesn't help.  You could do almost anything in a list of datasets

Comment: I didn't manage to make the list(the help function wasn't really helpful). But its actually very simple (I got some inspiration here [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) . What I did: `cluster_list = split(df, f = df&cluster)` That works, and retains a well organized list I can work on, thanks a lot! One followup question, how can I delete the `cluster`column afterwords in my list, like I did above in the subset using `select= -cluster`?